# Can't upload file in PHP using $ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I was trying to upload file on server using php with jQuery's `ajax()` function. Below is the code which I was trying. Things worked fine when I wrote PHP code on same page without jQuery, so there is no doubt that file upload is working.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var fd = new FormData();    
            fd.append("files", $("#fileinput").prop("files"));
            $.ajax({
                url: "imgupload_.php", 
                type:"POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: fd,
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='files' id="fileinput"/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

**imgupload_.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $target_dir = "images/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["files"]["name"]);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["files"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

If you want any other info please comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` but this is not set.

Instead of just this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
```

Use this to pull in any non-file input values (such as your submit button.)

```
var fd = new FormData(this);
```

Comment: Yupp. If I replace `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` with `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` and add `this` in `FormData`, it works. Thank you sir.